# True or false? (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

If $u$ and $v$ are two solutions of $Ax$ = $0$, then any vector in $Span(u, v)$ is
also a solution of $Ax = 0$.

I have doubts with $span(u,v)$. I do not know if the same thing $span(u\cup v)$ or $span(u)$ and $span(v)$ ?

Comment: What do YOU think?

Comment: Try to show that matrix multiplication is linear, namely $A(c\cdot v)=c\cdot Av$ where $c$ is a scalar and also $A(v+u)=Av+Au$.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman I have doubts with span(u,v). I do not know if the same thing span(u U v) or span(u) and span(v) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let w $\in Span(u,v)$ lets check whether w also a solution to Ax=0.
$w \in Span(u,v) \ so: $
$$w = au + bv \ s.t \ a,b \in F  $$
$$ than \ Aw = A(au+bv) = Aau + Abv = aAu + bAv = a*0 + b*0 = 0 + 0 = 0.$$
so , w  also a solution.